# invalid input syntax for integer (string)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a small app on apache2 server, the original database I used was Sqlite and now I am switching to Postgresql. The project uses Flask and Sqlalchemy and I get 500 Internal Error and error log says invalid input syntax for integer (items in name Column in Categories).

I have narrowed down the root of the problem down to the following lines but currently unable to solve the problem. 
addItem(DBSampleData.SampleItem)

```
def addItem(item):
    for i in item:
        items = Item(name=i[0], price=i[1], description=i[2],
                     category_ID=i[3], user_ID=i[4])
        session.add(items)
        session.commit
```

One of the SampleItem is:

```
    ('Maelstrom','2800',
     'A hammer forged for the gods themselves, '
     'Maelstrom allows its user to harness the '
     'power of lightning.',
     'Attack Speed',"guberland")
```

and the Categories DB setup part is:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

class Categories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    category_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.ID'))
    category = relationship(Categories)
    user_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.ID'))
    user = relationship(User)
```

The part of error log from apache2 is:

> [Tue Oct 31 16:17:18.814754 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1631:tid
>   140448423360256] [client 75.155.173.141:51827] psycopg2.DataError:
>   invalid input syntax for integer: “Attack Damage”

where the "Attack Damage" is the Categories.name 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your traceback?

Comment: you need to pass `ID` to `Categories`since you don't have `ID` set to auto-increment. Also, you forgot the parenthesis on `session.commit()`

Comment: @kstullich I tried to change the code to ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement =True) at the moment but still unable to solve the issue

Comment: Please do not post essential information in private forum posts. Please resubmit the traceback as an edit to this question.

Comment: @kstullich Regarding autoincrement: ["The default value is the string "auto" which indicates that a single-column primary key that is of an INTEGER type with no stated client-side or python-side defaults should receive auto increment semantics automatically"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement), which applies here.

Comment: the code in the question as stated doesn't allow for reproducing the problem - please try to create a MCVE. whats left is speculation: somewhere in your _real code_ you write ``Categories(some_variable)``, with ``some_variable`` being a ``str`` automapped to ``ID``  and not to ``name``

Comment: Did you change the name field after creating the database? The changes are not automatically applied to the database. Read the sqlalchemy docs about creating and dropping tables, or using migrations to manage schema changes. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables

Comment: @knitti I think that is exactly the cause of the problem,SQLite automaps the str to name but Postgre maps it to the ID which is Integer. Any suggestion to fix the problem without breaking the entire code? I have attached the entire db to the problem. Both Category_ID and User_ID in items are string input

Comment: Its almost irrelevant if they're string inputs if they cast correctly to integer, but "Attack Damage" is no integer. So ``Categories('Attack Damage')`` would probably map exactly to your problem while ``Categories(ID=7, name='Attack Damage')`` as an example would probably work. Again, this is pure speculation, as you didn't show minimal code which reproduces the error.

Comment: @knitti Yes, I think my input for both user_ID and Category ID are strings, but this worked perfectly fine using sqlite as they got automapped into name column, I have updated the post with more information, and wonder if there is a way to fix it without breaking most of the code..(changing input of user_ID and Category ID to integer will break most of my code )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have believed it, then I created a MCVE with sqlite, and it didn't raise an error. But it created an invalid database, [as you can see here](https://pastebin.com/QnNMfACw)

Obviously `"Attack Speed"` is not a `category_ID` and `"guberland"` is not an `user_ID`. You need either provide the ID to an existing object, or, much nicer for CRUD applications, a database object for the `relationship`:

```
db_item = Item(
    name=i[0], price=i[1], description=i[2], 
    category=Categories(name=i[3]), user=User(name=i[4]))
```

which works well and also creates the appropriate entries in the `user` and `categories` table.

Note: you have to *call* the `commit()` method of `session`.